# How to define an xml-configuration spring bean that is the result of a call to an enum's instance?

Tags: java, spring, enums, spring-bean, spring-ioc

I have an enum (this is kotlin, but it doesn't matter, could be Java too)

```
enum class AnEnum {
  A_VALUE {
    override fun aMethod(arg: ArgClass): AClass {
       //...
    }
  };
  abstract fun aMethod(arg: ArgClass): AClass
}
```

I need a bean in a spring xml bean that is the result of calling "aMethod" of an enum's value.

It seems I cannot use "factory-method" for this in the usual fashion:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.pckg.AClass" factory-method="???">
```

I know how to get a bean of the enum's value, if that helps to break down the problem:

```
   <bean id="aValueBean" class="my.pckg.AnEnum" factory-method="valueOf">
        <constructor-arg>
            <value>A_VALUE</value>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

I'm at a loss as to how to create a bean of type "AClass" that is the result of calling a method with arguments on the enum instance. I'm not very experienced with spring and I have used constructors or static methods before for bean definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`util:constant`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#xsd-schemas-util-constant) XML member to declare a bean for your enum constant `A_VALUE`

```
<util:constant id="myFactory" static-field="my.pckg.AnEnum.A_VALUE" />
```

Then use that bean as the [factory-bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-class-instance-factory-method) for your `AClass` bean

```
<bean id="myBean" class="my.pckg.AClass" factory-bean="myFactory" factory-method="aMethod">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="my.pckg.ArgClass"></bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: perfect, thanks, I found a very similar solution using factory-bean and factory-method and I was about to post it, so I know this works